# I am confused why this reasonable edit suggestion by a low rep user was rejected by two reviewers

Tags: discussion

Review: https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/1090627

I am the original author of this answer.  The suggested edit by a low rep user looks pretty reasonable to me.  To summarise: Measure twice before cutting!

Both rejects use this reason:
`This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.`

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Well - Its a fairly significant change, and arguably, no one other than you could have worked out if it was your intent. There was already a comment referring to this.

In a sense, its a judgement call, and 2 users with edit rights felt it wasn't a 'correct' edit. As OP, you kind of have better insight to what would be an appropriate edit to your answer, and by accepting the edit, you overruled the edit rejection.

Its roughly the system working as designed.

Comment: For what it's worth I would have rejected the edit proposal.  `dpkg -l | grep i386` is an unnecessary step in order to remove the packages since the very next step you are running `dpkg --remove-architecture i386` so other than a format change the edit virtually did nothing.  If and only if, the edit removed the `Might show: i386` statement, I would have approved it.  A command that "might" do something, doesn't belong in an answer, when you also indicate a command to remove all i386 packages